# How to add env map onto gltf object

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, mesh, texture-mapping

Im having quite a bit of trouble adding an environment map to a loaded GLTF / GLB file, as of now I get some sort of reflection instead of a black dot with a light point on it,

I was reading a bit of the document for three js and think I can pull it off with the standardmeshmaterial and applying it somehow to the object(gltf) and adding the mesh into the scene. I tried a similar mockup but the item disappears.  I dont know how to go about it, help guys.

This is the environment map im trying to apply to it, (or something similar)
https://hdrihaven.com/files/hdri_images/tonemapped/8192/venice_sunset.jpg

here is the codepen I am working on
https://codepen.io/8AD/pen/XWpxmpO

HTML

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/three@0.87.1/build/three.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawcdn.githack.com/mrdoob/three.js/d9f87fb1a2c5db1ea0e2feda9bd42b39b5bedc41/build/three.min.js"></script>
<!-- OrbitControls.js -->
<script src="https://rawcdn.githack.com/mrdoob/three.js/d9f87fb1a2c5db1ea0e2feda9bd42b39b5bedc41/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<!-- DRACOLoader.js -->
<script src="https://rawcdn.githack.com/mrdoob/three.js/d9f87fb1a2c5db1ea0e2feda9bd42b39b5bedc41/examples/js/loaders/DRACOLoader.js"></script>
<!-- GLTFLoader.js -->
<script src="https://rawcdn.githack.com/mrdoob/three.js/d9f87fb1a2c5db1ea0e2feda9bd42b39b5bedc41/examples/js/loaders/GLTFLoader.js"></script>

<div id="3dmain">

  
</div>
```

JS

```
var gltf = null;
var mixer = null;
var clock = new THREE.Clock();
var controls;
var camera;
init();
animate();

var renderCalls = [];
function render () {
requestAnimationFrame( render );
renderCalls.forEach((callback)=>{ callback(); });
}
render();

  
function init() {
    width = window.innerWidth;
    height = window.innerHeight;
    
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    
  var light = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffcc, 20, 200 );
light.position.set( 4, 30, 80 );
scene.add( light );

var light2 = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x20202A, 20, 100 );
light2.position.set( 30, -10, 30 );
scene.add( light2 );

  
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 60, width / height, 0.01, 10000 );
    camera.position.set(0, 3, 10);


    window.addEventListener( 'resize', function () {
      camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
      renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    }, false );
    
    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(100, 5, 100);
    var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
        color: "#707070"
    });
    
 
    var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
    manager.onProgress = function ( item, loaded, total ) {
        console.log( item, loaded, total );
    };

    var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
    loader.setCrossOrigin( 'anonymous' ); 
    
    
    var scale = 0.01;
    var url = "https://8ad.studio/wp-content/uploads/3D%20Assets/blimp.glb";
    
    loader.load(url, function (data) {
        gltf = data;
        var object = gltf.scene;
        object.scale.set(scale, scale, scale);
        //object.position.y = -5;
        //object.position.x = 4;
        object.castShadow = true;
        object.receiveShadow = true;

        var animations = gltf.animations;
        if ( animations && animations.length ) {
            mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer( object );
            for ( var i = 0; i < animations.length; i ++ ) {
                var animation = animations[ i ];
                mixer.clipAction( animation ).play();
            }
        }
        scene.add(object);
    });

    

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, alpha: true } );
    renderer.setClearColor( 0x000000, 0 );
    renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
    
    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera,);
      controls.rotateSpeed = 0.3;
controls.zoomSpeed = 0.9;

controls.minDistance = 14;
controls.maxDistance = 14;

controls.minPolarAngle = 0; // radians
controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI /2; // radians

controls.enableDamping = true;
controls.dampingFactor = 0.05;

var renderCalls = [];
renderCalls.push(function(){
  controls.update()
});

    renderer.setSize( width, height );
    renderer.gammaOutput = true;
    document.getElementById('3dmain').appendChild( renderer.domElement );
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    if (mixer) mixer.update(clock.getDelta());
    controls.update();
    render();
}

function render() {
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to include `RGBELoader` into your app for importing HDR textures and make use of `PMREMGenerator` in order to pre-process the environment map for the usage with a PBR material.

```js
var gltf = null;
var mixer = null;
var clock = new THREE.Clock();
var controls;
var camera;
var renderer;
init();
animate();

var renderCalls = [];

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderCalls.forEach((callback) => {
    callback();
  });
}
render();


function init() {
  width = window.innerWidth;
  height = window.innerHeight;

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffcc, 20, 200);
  light.position.set(4, 30, 80);
  scene.add(light);

  var light2 = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x20202A, 20, 100);
  light2.position.set(30, -10, 30);
  scene.add(light2);

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, width / height, 0.01, 10000);
  camera.position.set(0, 3, 10);


  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true,
    alpha: true
  });
  renderer.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
  renderer.toneMapping = THREE.ACESFilmicToneMapping;
  renderer.toneMappingExposure = 1;
  renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 0);
  renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;

  window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  }, false);

  var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(100, 5, 100);
  var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
    color: "#707070"
  });


  var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
  manager.onProgress = function(item, loaded, total) {
    console.log(item, loaded, total);
  };

  var scale = 0.01;
  var url = "https://8ad.studio/wp-content/uploads/3D%20Assets/blimp.glb";

  var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
  loader.setCrossOrigin('anonymous');

  const pmremGenerator = new THREE.PMREMGenerator(renderer);
  pmremGenerator.compileEquirectangularShader();

  const rgbeLoader = new THREE.RGBELoader();
  rgbeLoader.load('https://threejs.org/examples/textures/equirectangular/venice_sunset_1k.hdr', function(texture) {

    const envMap = pmremGenerator.fromEquirectangular(texture).texture;

    scene.background = envMap;
    scene.environment = envMap;

    texture.dispose();
    pmremGenerator.dispose();

    loader.load(url, function(data) {
      gltf = data;
      var object = gltf.scene;
      object.scale.set(scale, scale, scale);
      //object.position.y = -5;
      //object.position.x = 4;
      object.castShadow = true;
      object.receiveShadow = true;

      var animations = gltf.animations;
      if (animations && animations.length) {
        mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(object);
        for (var i = 0; i < animations.length; i++) {
          var animation = animations[i];
          mixer.clipAction(animation).play();
        }
      }
      scene.add(object);
    });

  });

  controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
  controls.rotateSpeed = 0.3;
  controls.zoomSpeed = 0.9;

  controls.minDistance = 14;
  controls.maxDistance = 14;

  controls.minPolarAngle = 0; // radians
  controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI / 2; // radians

  controls.enableDamping = true;
  controls.dampingFactor = 0.05;

  var renderCalls = [];
  renderCalls.push(function() {
    controls.update()
  });

  renderer.setSize(width, height);
  document.getElementById('3dmain').appendChild(renderer.domElement);
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  if (mixer) mixer.update(clock.getDelta());
  controls.update();
  render();
}

function render() {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
      margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.127/build/three.js"></script>
<!-- OrbitControls.js -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.127/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<!-- DRACOLoader.js -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.127/examples/js/loaders/DRACOLoader.js"></script>
<!-- GLTFLoader.js -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.127/examples/js/loaders/GLTFLoader.js"></script>
<!-- RGBELoader.js -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.127/examples/js/loaders/RGBELoader.js"></script>

<div id="3dmain">


</div>
```

The example applies the environment map to [Scene.environment](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=scene#api/en/scenes/Scene.environment). However, you could also traverse through the glTF object and apply it to each material's `envMap` property.

Comment: Beautiful!! Thank you very much.

Comment: You should always set tonemapping for HDR scenes. This scene is way over-bright. `renderer.toneMapping = THREE.ACESFilmicToneMapping; renderer.toneMappingExposure = 1;`